# Angular: How to close mat-menu and set focus on the next/ previous element

Tags: angular, angular-material, menu, accessibility, angular-material-7

I have code like below

```
<ng-container>
  <ng-container>
    <div class="class1" tabindex="0" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">
      <div class="customclass">
        <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
        <h2>Main Menu</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="myClass" >
    <div class="Custom">      
        <div mat-menu-item (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (keydown)="myFunc($event)"
         <div class="class2">
      <h3>Label</h3>     
        <div class="class3">
        <p> some text, <a href="link address">first link</a>.
            Some Test text and link <a href="address" >second link</a>
        </p>
      </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
  </mat-menu>
```

I want to navigate through links with the Tab key. So, I have added tabindex like below

```
 let myLinks = this.elRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('a');
   
    for (let i = 0; i <= anchors.length-1; i++) {
      myLinks[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
   }

myFunc(event: { stopPropagation: () => void }) {event.stopPropagation();}
```

I want to close the menu when I press shift+tab from the first link. or when I press the tab key after the last link inside the menu.

Also, when I shift+tab from the first link, focus should be on the Main Menu, and when I press the tab key after the last link, focus should be set on the next element.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t try to achieve this, and we’d need to know more about your use case to suggest a correct pattern.

A [`menu` in ARIA’s sense](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#menu) is reserved for desktop-like applications.

The keyboard control you describe is not the expected behaviour of a `menu`, in which *arrow keys* should be used to navigate between the menu items. According to [Keyboard navigation in Angular Material’s Menu documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#keyboard-interaction), this is already the case.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> only sets focus onto the menu once, the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> will quit the menu. This is what [ARIA calls a composite widget](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#managingfocus).

According to the Angular Material documentation, you should put `<button>` elements inside the menu.

As per ARIA standard, the only roles allowed inside a `menu` are `group`, `menuitem`, `menuitemcheckbox`, `menuitemradio` and `separator`.

`heading` (`<h3>`) or `paragraph` (`<p>`) are not allowed.

#### What to use instead

To align ARIA and Angular Material, the most appropriate component is probably `Sidenav`.

The [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG) suggest a *Disclosure Navigation Menu*](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/examples/disclosure-navigation/#mythical-page-content) for navigation, instead of a menu.

> Although this example uses the word "menu" in the colloquial sense to refer to a set of navigation links, it does not use the WAI-ARIA menu role.

Their example works both with <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys, and *arrow keys*.

If you prefer to continue using the `<mat-menu>` component, you should change it’s role. Be careful to get the roles right, though.